# Customize "Recently Viewed" list views

Tags: administration, metadata-api, metadata, list-view

I have been asked to customize the generic "Recently Viewed [object]" list views that are present for Salesforce objects (note: I do not mean the [object] Tab Search Layout.) The only problem is that this list view does not have an Edit option and just cloning it is not sufficient.

[image]

There does not appear to be any option to configure this under the Customize menu, either. Without resorting to custom JavaScript in the side panel, is there a way hide columns? Is it possible to update this via the Metadata API?

**Edit**

I used Ant to retrieve the Account object and every list view is present **except** the built-in Recently Viewed Accounts list view.

Comment: You can force edit it by URL hackery: learn the view's Id, paste it into edit link of another view, realize there's no "Save" button - only "Save As", inject the button by editing the HTML in Firebug, save... realize you've just broken the view and it shows all accounts. I think I need a new Dev Edition if I'll ever need my "recently viewed accounts" back ;(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this recently. It is not possible to do. Here is an idea to vote on: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpRoAAK.

Comment: I voted. I'm amazed that this is not possible.

Comment: @MikeChale I'm not. They only just published an API for working with recently viewed items in the last year or so. It was previously a totally opaque system.

Comment: I'm amazed I never noticed you couldn't modify it until a few weeks ago. How long have I been working with Salesforce, again?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the columns in the "Recently Viewed" List View:

In LEX:

- Setup->Object Manager
- Select the object
- Select Search Layouts
- Select Search Results->Edit
- Customize the list of Selected Fields, both which fields will be
  displayed and the order.  These fields will be displayed in the
  Recently View List View.
- Select Save.

Salesforce Reference:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_recent_records_list_lex.htm&type=5

Enjoy,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If search layouts are not there on custom objects you need to edit the object details and check the box 'Allow Search'. Once you've done that the search layouts will be available to choose and define the fields you want. The default layout will be the 'Recently viewed' layout